# How to calculate the range of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the cosine function, where the argument is given in radians.
> Let $W=[-2 \pi,-\pi] .$ What is $f(W)$?

a. (0,1)

b. (-1,0)

c. (-1,1)

d. na

I think it should be $(-1,1)$ as based on $\sin$ graph. But it is given wrong. How is it possible?

Comment: It is $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Well, indeed $\cos(-2\pi) = 1$ and $\cos(-\pi) = -1$, and cosine cannot have any values bigger than $1$ or smaller than $-1$. Therefore $[-1,1]$ looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(-2\pi)=f(0)=1$. Then $\cos$ decreases on $\left[-2\pi,-\pi\right]$, until it reaches $-1$ on $-\pi$. So, the answer is $[-1,1]$.

Comment: yes I got it. But my question is if [-1,1] is correct, then (-1,1) should be correct as (-1,1) is in [-1,1].

Comment: Since $(-1,1)\ne[-1,1]$, if $\cos(W)=[-1,1]$, then $f(W)\ne(-1,1)$.

Comment: Let $W \subseteq U .$ The image of $W$ with respect to $f$ is the set $f(W),$ where
$$
f(W)=\{f(u) \in V: u \in W\}=\{v \in V: v=f(u), u \in W\}
$$

Comment: Yes, I know what the range of a function is. If I didn't, I would not have answered your question, right?!

Comment: What I understand that "u" should be in W.  The domain of (-1,1) should be in [-2pi, -pi]. so why it is not correct based on this def. Sorry, I am forget to add these lines. I know you know about that. I am just trying to find what I missed when I was thinking according to this definition.

Comment: Take $1$, for instance. Since $1=\cos(-2\pi)$, $1$ belongs to the range of $f$. But $1\notin(-1,1)$. Therefore, the range of $f$ cannot possibly be $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117607/discussion-between-elizabeth-j-magee-and-jose-carlos-santos).